# The pusher from MyCorp, Inc. - who am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

At MyCorp U.S., Inc. I'm the pusher - one of the main keyboards on the org chart, the one you want to follow. Without me the corporation would be a cruel, harsh place, and would quickly collapse. I'm generous and kind, but also have a sinister side. One time I was arrested for some back-room deal, quite a serious infraction actually. Everyone was shocked!

Who am I?

**Edit:** added "wordplay" tag (though that is a relatively minor element in the riddle).

**Hint 1:**

> I am a thing, not a person.

**Hint 2:**

> My corporation's name might work better in Latin.

Comment: It's been a week since the last edit - any hints?

Comment: @question_asker sorry, got distracted by other things. I'll try to add something later today.

Comment: Oh, no problem, I was just curious about the solution and figured I'd give it another try if there were hints to be had. No rush!

Comment: @question_asker added some hints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a

> Heart

At MyCorp U.S., Inc.

> Corpus is latin for body - this is the corporation spoken of. I.e. My Corp U.S. = my Body

I'm the pusher - one of the main keyboards on the org chart,

> I push the blood round the body.

the one you want to follow.

> Usually good to follow your heart..

Without me the corporation would be a cruel, harsh place,

> Need to have a good heart and not be cruel.

and would quickly collapse.

> Without me working - the person will collapse.

I'm generous and kind, but also have a sinister side.

> Although usually people have a *generous* and *kind* hearts, they can have cruel hearts too.

One time I was arrested for some back-room deal, quite a serious infraction actually.

> The heart was arrested once (i.e. heart attack). The heart [Ejection **Fraction** Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ejection_fraction) measures the pumping of the heart. *(Not sure about the back-room deal thing).*

Everyone was shocked!

> Naturally, after a heart attack an electric shock was administered with a defibrillator.

Comment: Sinister could also just mean "left". And infarction / infraction maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> electricity

pusher:

> electricity is often [analogized](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/voltage-current-resistance-and-ohms-law/voltage) to water pressure; thus the sense of it being a "pusher"

main keyboard on the org chart:

> *I cannot make this connection*

the one you want to follow:

> you'd want electricity to be at the company first for lighting and HVAC; you'd turn the lights on before/as you entered a building.

without me the corporation would be a cruel, dark place, and would quickly collapse:

> electricity -> lighting for the "dark" piece; HVAC for being a "cruel" place to work; and so if no one worked at a corporation, it may soon collapse.

generous and kind:

> see above lighting and HVAC; also, electronics of all kinds (computers, cell phones) that enable people at a corporation to do work

have a sinister side:

> the inherent risks of electricity (electrocution; short circuiting, etc)

arrested for some back-room deal:

> by "arrested" I would imply "captured" or "stock-piled" as energy in UPS batteries; UPS' are often housed in a "back room"

everyone was shocked!

> hopefully not by the UPS, but maybe by static electricity!

Comment: This is a great answer - welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: Thank you! This answer would be better if I had that last piece, but I wanted to see if I was on the right track.

Comment: It's a very nice answer indeed, with some really good clue interpretations. Not the one I had in mind though...